# linking cell decimal place format to columns

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to enter a certain decimal value from 100.00 - 0.0001 into a cell and have the same decimal place be reflected in a column. I'm basically trying to make a one hundreds increment of one to ten thousands increment of 1 in a column, but have the place value dictated a number I enter into a cell.
Here is my mess, I cant get the formatting to link between the cells.

```
            5000    0.00240 0.00140
            5000    0.00230 0.00130
            5000    0.00220 0.00120
            5000    0.00210 0.00110
            5000    0.00200 0.00100
            5000    0.00190 0.00090
            5000    0.00180 0.00080
            5000    0.00070 0.00070
            5000    0.00160 0.00060
            5000    0.00150 0.00050
            5000    0.00140 0.00040
            5000    0.00130 0.00030
            5000    0.00120 0.00020
            5000    0.00110 0.00010
```

Entry   0.00100 5000    0.00100 0.00000
                5000    0.00000 -0.00010
                5000    0.00000 -0.00020
                5000    -0.00100    -0.00030
                5000    -0.00200    -0.00040
                5000    -0.00300    -0.00050
                5000    -0.00400    -0.00060
                5000    -0.00500    -0.00070
                5000    -0.00600    -0.00080
                5000    -0.00700    -0.00090
        support 5000    -0.00800    -0.00100
                5000    -0.00900    -0.00110
                5000    -0.01000    -0.00120
                5000    -0.01100    -0.00130

Answer (score 0):

To control the decimal place, look up the `POWER` function.  As an example: `=POWER(10,1-Column())` will be `1` in Column A (10<sup>0</sup>), `0.1` in Column B (10<sup>-1</sup>), `0.01` in Column C (10<sup>-2</sup>), etc.

> (As a second example: `=POWER(2,Column())` will be `2` in Column A (2<sup>1</sup>), `4` in Column B (2<sup>2</sup>), `8` in Column C (2<sup>3</sup>), etc)